# Game Maker Studio: Top 10 Highscores (Seriously)

Tags: game-maker

I feel really dumb for having to post this, but I've been trying to achieve this for an entire week now and I'm getting nowhere!

I'm trying to create a highscore board. Top 10 scores, saved to an INI file. I have searched every single thing on the entire internet ever. I just do not get it.

So what I have tried is this...

I have a "load_room" setup. When this room loads, it runs this code:

```
ini_open('score.ini')
ini_write_real("Save","highscore_value(1)",highscore_value(1));
ini_write_string("Save","highscore_name(1)",highscore_name(1));
ini_close();

room_goto(room0);
```

Then when my character dies:

```
myName = get_string("Enter your name for the highscore list: ","Player1"); //if they enter nothing, "Player1" will get put on the list
highscore_add(myName,score);

ini_open('score.ini')
value1=ini_write_real("Save","highscore_value(1)",0);
name1=ini_write_string("Save","highscore_name(1)","n/a");
ini_close();
highscore_clear();
highscore_add(myName,score);

score = 0;
game_restart();
```

I'm not worried about including the code to display the scores as I'm checking the score.ini that the game creates for the real values added.

With this, I seem to be able to save ONE score, and that's all. I need to save 10. Again, I'm sorry for asking the same age-old question, but I'm really in need of help and hoping someone out there can assist!

Thanks so much,
Lee.

Comment: I think you've confused `ini_write_real` and `ini_read_real`.

Comment: For anyone who visits this page, let me point out that there are a few extensions out there for creating an online high score system that allow players to see other players high scores. Kind of cool. See https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=game+maker+online+highscore

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you use save in `load_room` instead load?
2. Why you clear the table after die?
3. You need to use loop for save each result.

For example, loading:

```
highscore_clear();

ini_open("score.ini");
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    var name = ini_read_string("Save", "name" + string(i), "");
    var value = ini_read_real("Save", "value" + string(i), 0);
    if value != 0
        highscore_add(name, value);
}
ini_close();

room_goto(room0);
```

Die:

```
myName = get_string("Enter your name for the highscore list: ","Player1");
highscore_add(myName, score);

ini_open("score.ini");
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    ini_write_string("Save", "name" + string(i), highscore_name(i));
    ini_write_string("Save", "value" + string(i), string(highscore_value(i)));
}
ini_close();

score = 0;
game_restart();
```

And few more things...

```
score = 0;
```

You need do it when game starts, so here it is unnecessary.

```
get_string("Enter your name for the highscore list: ","Player1");
```

Did you read note in help?

> NOTE: THIS FUNCTION IS FOR DEBUG USE ONLY. Should you require this functionality in your final game, please use `get_string_async`.

I used `ini_write_string(..., ..., string(...));` instead `ini_write_real()` because second case will save something like `1000.000000000`, and first case will save just `1000`.